# How can I format code in Xcode like in Eclipse or NetBeans?

Tags: xcode, code-formatting

How can I format code in Xcode like in Eclipse or NetBeans? I have not found any options in the menu. Is there a hot key for this, or is it simply not available in Xcode?

Comment: I should say that Xcode should a better job now! Its really not competing with Eclipse, Netbeans or Visual Studio!

Comment: Duplicate of [XCode 4; How to format code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6543026/3425536)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode source automatic formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573968/xcode-source-automatic-formatting)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select some text and then: Edit->Format->Re-Indent

You can bind this to a hotkey in the preferences.

Comment: This is the closest thing Xcode has to built-in formatting support.

Comment: as of 2021 if anyone want it's solution, check my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270147/2049623

Comment: -1, as this is NOT the code formatting any way - look into the Android Studio for the actuall code formating capabilities...

Answer (score 59):

In Xcode 4, it's been moved to `Editor > Structure > Re-Indent` command (and has a default shortcut of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> ).

Answer (score 14):

Well, first of all welcome to 2021. I know it's a very old question but still people like me visit this and for those people, I'm putting out multiple available solutions in one answer that worked for me after 2 hours of research and testing.

#### Re-Indent

As everyone else is suggesting, it's one of the default solution if you just want to re-indent the lines of code:

Goto: `Editor -> Structure -> Re-Indent` or use shortcut <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

#### Using Xcode Extensions

There are 2 extensions I found and used which works charmingly for me.

**1)** [SwiftFormat](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat): mentioning the steps to install the xcode extension here from the readme.

> Like the command-line tool, you can install the SwiftFormat for Xcode
> extension application via Homebrew. Assuming you already have Homebrew
> installed, type:
>
> `$ brew install --cask swiftformat-for-xcode`

- open the **SwiftFormat for Xcode.app** that you just installed. there you can change the rules of formatting.
- After that, open the `system preference -> extensions -> xcode source editor` and mark the checkbox for SwiftFormat.
- Restart the Xcode

Voila! You're good to go. you can use three options. format selected code, format entire file OR just lint file.

**2)** [Swimat](https://github.com/Jintin/Swimat): (it is already mentioned in one of the answer here by @Guy Daher) steps to install from readme

> Install via [homebrew-cask](https://caskroom.github.io/)
>
> Homebrew latest version
>
> `brew install --cask swimat`

- Similar to above extension installation, open the **Swimat.app** if it does not open then try to sove it from `system preferences -> security & privacy -> open swimat app`
- after opening, click on install in ./bin folder to make it work globally (not sure about this step but I just did it)
- Restart Xcode

now you can goto `editor -> swimat -> format`

Bingo! You're good to go.

#### Additional uninvited help

You can simply set the keybinding to use any of this command. i.e. I've set the android studio default command to reformat the code as <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

**ps** If anyone else found a better extension, please let me know in comment, I'll add it to the list.

Comment: This sounds promising as a real code formatter (unbelievable that Xcode, after all those years, does not have such a basic feature)...

Could you please recommend the better one (solely to save our time when trying to pick one)... Soory for my laziness :)

Comment: I used Swimat most of the time. It's my personal preference due to certain features and easily configurable.

Answer (score 9):

Other than re-indentation (Edit > Format > Re-Indent), not really.  However, Xcode does have support for scripts (the menu to the right of the Window menu), so you could conceivably write a script that formats your code how you like it.

Edit: here are some links that touch on this subject:

- <strike>http://hackertoys.com/2008/09/18/adding-a-code-beautifier-script-to-xcode</strike> (dead link)
- <strike>http://8020world.com/jcmendez/2006/11/geeky-stuff/software/adding-a-script-menu-to-xcode-to-reformat-code-using-astyle</strike> (dead link)

Answer (score 4):

Here are the shortcuts, to format the code in Xcode

**1.Format entire code (entire class/controller)**

select the entire code and **press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd>  on mac** to format your code.

**2.Format particular block of code**

select the code and press

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for right move and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> for left move

Note : as per @JavierGiovannini sugesstion you can do using Editor Menu option

**3.Select code --> Go to Editor --> Structure --> Re-Indent**

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorite code formatter is [Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net).
It has many, many options, so I also suggest you download [UniversalIndentGUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/), a GUI to help set Uncrustify's behavior to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

#### XCode 8 Extensions

Another option is to use an extension like [Swimat](https://github.com/Jintin/Swimat). Does the job for me. However, the caveat is that it does not format on save due to the restrictive Xcode Extension APIs, but they're trying to find a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Not saying this is best approach, but for completeness, if you cut and then paste the code back in, Xcode will automatically format it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In v.4 you can make some adjustments through xCode preferences...

[Fix code indentation in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558709/fix-code-indentation-in-xcode/7609419#7609419)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>^</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> (<kbd>control</kbd> - capital <kbd>i</kbd>)
: format the current line

<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> 
: format the whole code file

Answer (score -4):

Try this solution:  ⌘A [⌘K ⌘F]

[image]