# Automatic column align along colons in Xcode and Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, formatting, coding-style

Is there a macro or preference setting that would automatically align method parameters along the columns and colons in Xcode?

Basically a shortcut to turn this:

```
  [object methodWithParam:theParam another:theOtherValue something:theSomethingValue else:theElseValue];
```

automatically into this:

```
  [object methodWithParam:theParam
                  another:theOtherValue
                something:theSomethingValue
                     else:theElseValue];
```

Is it possible to get this working with code completion? In other words when I tab complete a method it would automatically wrap the formatting into this style? And what about preexisting code? Can I put my caret inside a method, press a keyboard shortcut and auto format the parameters?

Comment: This gets done automatically when you manually break the line between the arguments, but I suppose you're asking for a shortcut that does this for the whole method call, right?

Comment: Yeah, basically whatever process reduces typing. I am still new to xcode and mastering the editor.

Comment: I don't find this a better format for coding. I think XCode should use full width of screen other wise Apple wouldn't have provided the broader area for coding.

Comment: @Developer As with most aspects of programming, there is a lot of personal taste that comes into play. I came to this question today because I miss the auto-alignment of the colons since Swift came out. I hope I just haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It has no built in support for this. See the answers in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573968/xcode-source-automatic-formatting) for some tips.