# How to stop XCode from inserting spaces between type and *

Tags: pointers, coding-style, autocomplete, xcode4.2

Our style guide says (for whatever reason that isn't important to this question) no space between the type and the `*` in selector definitions.

I.e., this is bad:

```
- (void)foo:(Foo *)foo {
```

...and this is good:

```
- (void)foo:(Foo*)foo {
```

Is there a way to tell XCode's auto-complete to stop doing the bad thing and do the good thing?

Comment: Ideally I'd like an XCode-based solution, but the answer may be that XCode just doesn't let you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: you can't without using some 3rd party software or script.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a post about code formatting in XCode: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/08/07/code-formatting-in-xcode/

I believe that the `sp_before_ptr_star=add` line in the config file (https://gist.github.com/841452) is just the opposite to what you want to do, so probably it should be `sp_before_ptr_star=remove`.

But I guess this is something to be done AFTER the code has been auto-completed.

Check this comment also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1610123/1117650, there is a script you might want to use.

Answer (score 0):

may not be the best answer but you could opt to use this IDE

[AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/)