# Default opening curly braces in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I am using Xcode, and noticed that Xcode's default auto creation and completion of functions makes opening curly braces go into new lines. For example

```
(void) this_is_what_xcode_does
{
    // Opening braces on a line of its own - default format
}
```

I do not like that, I would like the opening braces to be on the same line as the function name. Just like below

```
(void) this_is_what_i_want_xcode_to_do {
    // Opening braces on the same line as the function - my preferred format
}
```

How can I change the default Xcode format/behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: Just be thankful you're not using Visual Studio.

Comment: @HotLicks - As a matter of fact, Visual Studio is far better IDE than Xcode. I use Xcode, Visual Studio, and Eclipse, and I am neither an "Apple guy" or a "Windows guy"; I do not identify myself by a product, but truth is, Visual Studio is way better than Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Xcode is missing a good, customisable code formatting settings. You can find some external plugins that are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573968/xcode-source-automatic-formatting). Personally I haven't tried them. So in short, Xcode is missing that feature.

As a side tip I can mention that AppCode has a quite good way to format code in the way you want and the keyboard shortcuts for auto formatting code and optimising imports.