# Does Xcode have code autoformat feature?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is any way to autoformat a source code in the Xcode IDE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode source automatic formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573968/xcode-source-automatic-formatting)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code Formating In Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510915/code-formating-in-xcode)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

There isn't really an autoformat option in Xcode.

There is an option `^I` (Control-I) to re-indent the code, which will re-align the code according to the tab width set in your preferences, but that's about as far as it goes.

You might have better luck with a text editor like TextMate? I don't know for certain, but I know it supports Objective-C and has some macros, there may be a reformat option?

Comment: For more control of the code formatting, you can try uncrustify: http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I keep forgetting this every time I don't use XCode for some months. And then I search again and always return to this thread. Thanks for the n-th time! :D

Answer (score 71):

Yes Xcode 4 has an autoformat feature.

Try following:

1. Select text. <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> .

Please also see here:
[Fix code indentation in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558709/fix-code-indentation-in-xcode)

Comment: That's just re-indenting but not autoformatting. But good to know anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 31):

One trick is to select the code (either "select all" or just the section you want to re-format) - then cut, then paste it back. This triggers the automatic code formatting in the Xcode editor.

Comment: @Joe: oh dear - it works in Xcode 2.x and 3.x - you might want to file a bug report at http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: @FearlessFuture: if it’s a large block of code you have to do it explicitly - there’s a menu item for doing this in recent versions of Xode so the above trick is somewhat redundant these days anyway.

Answer (score 9):

ctrl + I will auto format the code you're selecting

Answer (score 4):

[ClangFormat-Xcode](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode) is an Xcode plugin available in Alcatraz. This is a nice code format tool.

Comment: Also developed https://github.com/ML-Works/AnyFormat-Xcode plugin to format code with any custom script.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the Copy & Paste method (Cmd-A then Cmd-C then Cmd-V) worked in XCode 4 and was the method I used whilst I was waiting for google to display the results (Mac was going slow!)

Answer (score 0):

To change, go to xCode => Preferences => Text Editing => Indentation => Automatically indent based on syntax.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558709/fix-code-indentation-in-xcode/7609419#7609419)

Answer (score 0):

#### Format on Save

For anyone wanting to format on save this is what I did. It's a bit janky but it works well. ⤵

---

1. To get started pick out a formatter for Xcode. I'd recommend SwiftFormat but here's a list of a [bunch of them](https://github.com/theswiftdev/awesome-xcode-extensions) and other handy extensions.
2. Once you have a formatter picked out assign it a hotkey in Xcode that's not taken such as `CMD + ~`
3. Then download a shortcut mapper such as BetterTouchTool.
4. In your shortcut mapper simply setup `CMD + S` for Xcode and set it to actually use your shortcut you set for your fomatter. Like this ⤵
   [image]