# Custom autoformat in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I need a tool for Xcode that do an autoformat to my c++ code, I checked this answer 
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243348/does-xcode-have-code-autoformat-feature), I checked this [link2](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) and I checked "TextMate" also.

but I do not know is that possible to create a custom code format like

1- one space before and after both "=" and "=="

2- if condition format should be like the following format

```
if (condition || condition) {
}
```

the "{" should be in the same line of "if", one space between each condition, and the final "}" should be in new line.

I prefer to use some addon tool in the xcode not external one.

Comment: Have you checked-out `clang-format` and the Xcode plugin to use it?  It's a bit of pain to get (you have to use a pre-built binary from `llvm` themselves, last time I installed it).

Comment: @chesh, that's one did not support custom format!

Comment: @HazemAbdullah have you taken a look at users romanvbabenko and matm answers in the post I linked ?