# How to format code in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, format, keyboard-shortcuts, code-formatting

I wonder how can I format my code to align it neatly? Does it have a feature similar to Eclipse's <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>?

Comment: I have gathered all available options as in Feb 2021 in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270147/2049623

Answer (score 785, accepted):

*Select first* the text you want to format and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> first if you wish to format all text in the selected file.

**Note**: this procedure only re-indents the lines, it does *not* do any advanced formatting.

---

### In Xcode 12 beta:

The new key binding to re-indent is <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Quick question though, do you recall where you can edit the templates that Xcode uses for its formatting? In Xcode 3 I had customized mine a bit, but I can't find the bookmark I had that said how to do it, and, the technique is probably different now.

Comment: it doesn't format code. it just reindents lines. Just like the menu item says. It doesn't take care of adding or removing extra spaces between various symbols

Comment: I think it is i, Ctrl+i, not Ctrl+L

Comment: Yeah, still no advanced formatting (Feb 2020)... looks like a lot of people (myself included) came to Xcode from a more engineering-oriented IDE. I personally find that Xcode is missing a lot of productivity/navigation/auto-complete features I really got used to in Eclipse/IntelliJ products... to me it feels like an Apple notepad app compared to IDEA :/

Comment: There is a solution! The solution is to use a Automation-Script. Check out this Tutorial for a detailed step-by-step instruction. https://luisramos.dev/xcode-format-and-save

Comment: -1, as this is NOT a full code formatting, it is just very bad re-indentation - look into the IntelliJ Idea / Android Studio for what actually is the code formatting...

Answer (score 119):

Key combination to format all text on open file:

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>

Answer (score 31):

1. Select the block of code that you want indented.
2. Right-click (or, on Mac, Ctrl-click).
3. Structure → Re-indent

Answer (score 22):

I would suggest taking a look JetBrains AppCode IDE. It has a Reformat Code command. I have come from a C# background and used Visual Studio with Jetbrains Resharper plugin, so learning AppCode has been a pleasure because many of the features in Resharper also exist in AppCode!

Theres too many features to list here but could well be worth checking out

- http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/features/index.html
- http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/

Comment: Good tip but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, AppCode sunsetted.