# Shortcut to apply format for XCode?

Tags: objective-c, eclipse, xcode

I Eclipse there is a shortcut to apply format which is:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

**Is there a similar shortcut in Xcode which fixes the formats like tabs, etc.?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode 4; How to format code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543026/xcode-4-how-to-format-code) - same still applies for XCode 6.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want *Editor -> Structure -> Re-Indent* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>). I does not change the position of braces and things like that. For that, you'd need to use an external code formatting tool like Uncrustify.

Comment: `clang-format` is better still.  There is a [plugin](https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode) for Xcode.