# Missing return in a function expected to return CGPoint

Tags: ios, swift, macos

So I'm new to coding and have been trying to create a game called zig zag but the tutorial I've been watching is kind of old and have been running into numerous problems but the most annoying so far is this I keep receiving the error message "Missing return in a function expected to return CGPoint" and have tried for hours to fix it with no luck and was wondering if anyone new what to do

[image]

Comment: add your code not code image.

Comment: By the way you have extra close braces.

Comment: please format your code. Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543026/how-to-format-code-in-xcode

Comment: it will help you to find extra braces.

Comment: Press ⌘A and then ⌃I to reindent the code. Then you might see the problem (unbalanced or badly balanced braces).

Answer (score 0):

Check your braces are balanced. Select All your code (Cmd + A) and format it by using keyboard shortcut Ctrl + i. Then check curly braces in your code. Think you have an additional closing brace.